# Hspice DC simulation Help

Tags: hspice

I new to hspice, i searched on the hspice docs, but still cannot clear about this option. What does this option actually effect on simulation.

> .param dummy=1
>   .dc dummy 1 1 1

Please help me on this!
Thanks very much!

Comment: I am confused, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this will run the simulation with dummy = 1.

The .dc command defaults to a linear scale, but you've put 1 as the starting point, ending point, and increment.

If you want to run the simulation with dummy = 1, then 2, then 3 for example use
.dc dummy 1 3 1 (i.e. 1 to 3 incremented by 1)

see http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/SPICEsummary.htm